# How to use a cursor event in Angular?

Tags: angular

How do i make a mouse event when the cursor point in the `amount` it will display all the decimal? (please see the example below)

html

```
<p >{{amount.total ? round(amount.total) : '--'}} </p>
```

ts

```
  round(deci) {
    dec = dec.replace('%', '');
    dec = this.env.moneyFormat(dec , 2);
    return dec + '%';
  }
```

mouseLeave

```
129.24%
```

mouseEnter

```
129.2445131545%
```

another example
[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk2mh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mouseenter and mouseleave event on your paragraph tag.

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bl5e2z?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a percent pipe or a decimal pipe to format your number :

```
<p class="amount">
    <span class="short">{{amount.total | percent:'1.2-2'}}</span>
    <span class="long">{{amount.total | percent:'1.8-8'}}</span>
</p>
```

And use CSS to hide/show them :

```
.amount .long {
    display: none;
}
.amount .short{
    display: block;
}
.amount:hover .long {
    display: block;
}
.amount:hover .short{
    display: none;
}
```

(or something along the line I haven't tested this exact code)

Answer (score 0):

You are close... you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in your HTML template

Just like this:

```
<p (mouseenter)="mouseEntered = true" (mouseleave)="mouseEntered = false">
  {{ mouseEntered ? amount : amount.toFixed(2) }}%
</p>
```

Make sure you define your variables in your .ts component as such:

```
mouseEntered = false;
amount = 129.2445131545;
```

**Note**: I think is better if you treat `amount` as a number, instead of a string. The percent sign can be added to the HTML after the curly braces in the `<p>` element, just like I did in the HTML above.